# Android view customization problem

Tags: android-layout, android

I am trying to organize my view with the following view widgets -

- TextView (should fill the width of the screen and has a specific height)
- Custom View Drawn using Draw() (fill the width and should start after the above textview and fill the screen)

I am trying to write a board game and hence the custom view drawn.

My problem is what is best Layout to use for this?

Can I use a TableLayout and have these two views as one column each? I thought that would do the trick but which ever layout I use for the Custom View just does not fill the screen even though the tablerow I am drawing it in fills the screen.

I hope I was able to explain myself properly. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/tl_question"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:shrinkColumns="1"
            android:stretchColumns="2">

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/question"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFFFFF"   
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="9dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
                    <com.ac.gui.CustomView
                        android:id="@+id/custom_board"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:keepScreenOn="true" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="ASDFASDF"
                android:textColor="#ffFFFFFF"   
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="9dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"/>

           <com.ac.gui.CustomView

            android:layout_below="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tested a different layout in place of yours and it works fine. It should work with yours as well.

RelativeLayout allows you to position items, well, relative to one another.
You'll notice the attribute "layout_below" on your custom view where i specify the ID of the view to place it under.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes a lot of sense. I was over thinking it. What do I do if I want to add another textview or button below the customview? Ideally I don't want to fix the height of the custom view. So I would want it to be relative to the height of the textview below it. Can that be done?

Comment: Of course! What you'd want to do is place the TextView ABOVE the custom view in the XML. Make sure to give the TextView an Id. Then, in your CustomView, add the attribute android:layout_above="@id/whateveryounamedit". Now your custom view will show below the Question text view and above the new text view! :) You should place the TextView before the Custom View because the XML is read inline. So, if you put the layout_above attribute on the CustomView with the TextView below it, it would not know of the resource you were referencing.(This may have been fixed in the more recent Eclipse plugins)